# Mobile Facebook Connect to my own server

Tags: ios, mobile, facebook

On iOS (or any mobile), after a successful login, how should I handle login with my own server?

Should I send the token and user id to my server and re-verify it, or is there a better practice?

I obviously don't want to send only the FB user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FBConnect SDK should automatically save login information on the device, so every time the user goes to use the Facebook feature of your app, they are automatically logged in.

Comment: Yes, but that covers only FB side, what's the best practice to verify the FB user with my own server? I could send the token over the network and verify on my server, just asking if that's the best practice. Thanks.

Comment: Wondered about security, but it seems to be fine as long as my app secret is secure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of FBConnect doesn't provides obvious proxy authentication, but the old version did. I think you could create this proxy manually, ie. pass all login data, except api secret key to proxy, proxy adds secret key and sends request to FB. Then it returns response of FB server as it is.